# Creating columns from unorganized data based on substrings

Tags: r, sorting, substring, reshape, grepl

I faced the following problem with my thesis data. I have a data frame with horizontally unorganized string-cells after the first column "id". I want to organize strings within row, so that all strings beginning with the identical first 4 characters would stay in the same column.

Since there is a limited amount of relevant categories (less than 20), I could do this manually, first for "Arra", then for "Comm" and so on. I tried this with `grepl` but failed to return the original string of cell. I got only TRUE/FALSE. I would appreciate your help a lot!

My current data looks like this. (I left NA cells empty)

```
id  col2              col3               col4         col5
3   Commitment 100    Lead Mgmt 15      Arranger 50
8   Arrangement 20    Front-end 80
16  Lead mgmt 40      Commitmnt 20
17
20  Arranger 50
```

And this is what it should look like:

```
id  Arra           Comm            Fron         Lead
3   Arranger 50    Commitment 100               Lead Mgmt 15
8   Arrangement 20                 Front-end 80
16                 Commitmnt 20                 Lead mgmt 40
17
20  Arranger 50
```

Comment: Please share an extract of your data using `dput()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mydf), "id", na.rm = TRUE)[value != ""][
  , ind := substr(value, 1, 4)], id ~ ind, value.var = "value", fill = "")
#    id           Arra           Comm         Fron         Lead
# 1:  3    Arranger 50 Commitment 100              Lead Mgmt 15
# 2:  8 Arrangement 20                Front-end 80             
# 3: 16                  Commitmnt 20              Lead mgmt 40
# 4: 20    Arranger 50
```

And, with similar logic, in the "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- ""
mydf %>%
  gather(var, val, starts_with("col")) %>%
  filter(val != "") %>%
  mutate(ind = substr(val, 1, 4)) %>%
  select(-var) %>%
  spread(ind, val)
#   id           Arra           Comm         Fron         Lead
# 1  3    Arranger 50 Commitment 100         <NA> Lead Mgmt 15
# 2  8 Arrangement 20           <NA> Front-end 80         <NA>
# 3 16           <NA>   Commitmnt 20         <NA> Lead mgmt 40
# 4 20    Arranger 50           <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
```

Sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c(3L, 8L, 16L, 17L, 20L), col2 = c("Commitment 100", 
    "Arrangement 20", "Lead mgmt 40", "", "Arranger 50"), col3 = c("Lead Mgmt 15", 
    "Front-end 80", "Commitmnt 20", "", ""), col4 = c("Arranger 50", 
    "", "", "", ""), col5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", 
    "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

If there are duplicated stubs in your original data, for example, if "col5" in row 1 had another "commitment" value:

```
mydf$col5[1] <- "Commitment 99"
```

you can try something like this:

```
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mydf), "id", na.rm = TRUE)[value != ""][
  , ind := substr(value, 1, 4)], 
  id ~ ind + rowid(id, ind), value.var = "value", fill = "")
#    id         Arra_1         Comm_1        Comm_2       Fron_1       Lead_1
# 1:  3    Arranger 50 Commitment 100 Commitment 99              Lead Mgmt 15
# 2:  8 Arrangement 20                              Front-end 80             
# 3: 16                  Commitmnt 20                            Lead mgmt 40
# 4: 20    Arranger 50
```

or this:

```
dcast(melt(as.data.table(mydf), "id", na.rm = TRUE)[value != ""][
  , ind := substr(value, 1, 4)], 
  id ~ ind, value.var = "value", fun = function(x) x[1], fill = "")
#    id           Arra           Comm         Fron         Lead
# 1:  3    Arranger 50 Commitment 100              Lead Mgmt 15
# 2:  8 Arrangement 20                Front-end 80             
# 3: 16                  Commitmnt 20              Lead mgmt 40
# 4: 20    Arranger 50
```

depending on your desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So far I managed to get only number of each variable type (just like in your example but instead having "Arranger 50" I have "1" in col "Arra"). I think it's because there exists for example multiple Commitment or Front-end values in certain rows. Do you know any simple solution for that, like ignoring multiple values? Currently I'm working on it to remove those rows and will get back to you. Btw, I tried to get the sample data for you as you adviced, but I didn't manage to extract smaller sample than whole data out from R with dput(). I don't know why.

Comment: @PauliLohi, you need to decide whether you want to drop or whether you want to add an indicator variable to allow for multiple.

Comment: If there's any chance to allow for multiple, it would be great.

Comment: @PauliLohi, I hope you've had a chance to see the two alternatives at the end of my answer. The first option allows for multiple. The second option just extracts the first value.